# Python dictionary dynamic update

Tags: python, dictionary

so I have this dictionary x created from this function

```
    olist = ['a/b/c','a/b/c/d','b/c/d','x/y/z','a/b','d/e/f','i/j/k']

    def bulkFeed(objlist):
        x = {}
        for obj in objlist:
            #pdb.set_trace()
            dn_len = len(obj)
            if dn_len not in x:
                x[dn_len] = {}
            if obj not in x[dn_len]:
                x[dn_len][obj] = {}
            x[dn_len][obj].update({"commit":1,"ObjectRef":obj})
        return x

obj_dict = bulkFeed(olist)

 >>> obj_dict
    {3: {'a/b': {'commit': 1, 'ObjectRef': 'a/b'}}, 5: {'a/b/c': {'commit': 1, 'ObjectRef': 'a/b/c'}, 'd/e/f': {'commit': 1, 'ObjectRef': 'd/e/f'}, 'b/c/d': {'commit': 1, 'ObjectRef': 'b/c/d'}, 'x/y/z': {'commit': 1, 'ObjectRef': 'x/y/z'}, 'i/j/k': {'commit': 1, 'ObjectRef': 'i/j/k'}}, 7: {'a/b/c/d': {'commit': 1, 'ObjectRef': 'a/b/c/d'}}}
```

what I want to do is something like this in obj_dict

```
if 'a/b/c'.startswith('a/b'):
    update commit to 0 in 'a/b/c' level
if  'a/b/c/d'.startswith('a/b/c'):
    update commit to 0 in 'a/b/c/d' level

keep doing for every item in dictionary until reaching end of dict
```

Thanks any answer/headsup will be very helpful.
'a/b/c' stems from inner dictionary level for instance 'a/b/c/d' stems

Comment: is it possible that `not 'a/b/c/d'.startswith('a/b/c'):`?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: I think you need to show us more, the question isn't clear.  For instance, where do the "startswith" strings come from?

Comment: Also, if you described the actual high-level problem you're solving, it could help, too. Understanding _why_ some code has been written is very important for troubleshooting.

Comment: How do we find the order in the elements in obj_dict you wish to modify?  The order seems important in the operation you are proposing but you do not explain wha the sort keys are or how obj_dict should be sorted for iteration.  Hope this helps!